# XML element name with special characters while serialising

Tags: c#, .net, xml, element

While serialising the object to the XML I use the attribute convention like `[XmlElement("MyData:Pool1")]` for me it does the job but the XML looks like

```
<_x005C_MyData_x003A_Pool1 >
```

I presume it convert to the colon or any special chars to some other formats, I tried changing with backslash, @ and $ signs preceding to the string, but it didn't  helped me.

Any suggestions apart from using string / regex replace ?

```
  private void Serlise(Interface request)
    {
        var xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Interface));
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        var xml = "";

        using (var encoder = new CustomEncoder())
        {
            using (var  writer = XmlWriter.Create(encoder))
            {
                xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, request,ns);
                xml = encoder.ToString();
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(@"output.xml", xml);
    }
```

Below is the class to be serialised

---

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
```

[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.foo1.com/bar/test/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "Pool", Namespace = "http://www.foo1.com/bar/test/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Root
{

```
private Tester adminField;

private string versionField;

[XmlElement("Test:Pool1")]
public Tester Admin
{
    get
    {
        return this.adminField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.adminField = value;
    }
}

 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string Version
{
    get
    {
        return this.versionField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.versionField = value;
    }
}
```

}

NOTE : *Slightly adjusted namespace & class name on XML due to NDA*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><q1:MydataPool Version="1" xmlns:q1="http://www.foo1.com/bar/test"><q1:Data Id ="000123" Function="Hi"><q1:Hello Test="Abcd"  /></q1:Data></q1:MydataPool>
```

Comment: `_x005C_MyData_x003A_Pool1` is a valid XML name. Have a look [here at the W3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar). There you will see that an  *XML Name* can (only) start with an *NameStartChar* like `":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | ...` followed by additional *NameStartChars and NameChars* like `"-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]`.

Comment: This is a common convention for generating a valid element name from a string that contains characters that aren't allowed in an element name. What exactly is your problem with it? It isn't pretty, but it's a sensible way around the restrictions.

Comment: Probably you should use a namespace with the MyData prefix?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, I tried with namespace but no luck.

Comment: @MichaelKay, my real problem is the API is validating the kind of XML chunk I pass to it. It actively reject the one with strange chars like _x003A_ . since I have no control over the API I had to stick with their conventions.

Comment: @zx485, I dont say its invalid, its perfectly ok for me while parsing or anything like that, but as i said above its the API which is expecting the : instead of the char sets you mentioned above.

Comment: @jidh - then they probably expect that `<Pool1>` will be in some namespace with assigned to the prefix `MyData` that is bound to some namespace URL not shown in your question.  Can you [edit] your question to show us a [mcve] with a complete, simplified, well-formed XML document you want to create, and the classes and code you are trying to use to create it?

Comment: @dbc, I tweak the question and provided essential details to reproduce locally

Comment: OK, but might you please [edit] your question to include your code and XML as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for textual data, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  We also need to know the XML you want to get not just the XML you are actually getting.

Comment: @dbc, I tried with image because of 2 reasons , 1 - while pasting the class on 'code' section it did't fit well (still you can see the code section is a bit out of focus of code zone. 2- Already the XML generation code i pasted the rest is just CLR class that you can see and verify. I corrected it now

Comment: @dbc, I think  I got a workaround , if you see my XML above, it speaks well. Just change my prefix of <q1 to 'MyData' and the attribute notation above my class's property will be 'Pool'. since the : just appears already after the prefix. So changing the prefix will be the focus .

Answer (score 1):

Specify the namespace in the property attribute:

```
[XmlElement("Pool1", Namespace = "url")]
public Tester Admin
```

Set a prefix for this namespace:

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("MyData", "url");
```

In the result, you will get

```
<MyData:Pool1>
```